# C sockets receive file

Tags: c, file, sockets, ftp, transfer

I'm developing very simple ftp client. I have created a data connection sockets, but I can't transfer file successfully:

```
FILE *f = fopen("got.png", "w");
int total = 0;
while (1){      
    memset(temp, 0, BUFFSIZE);
    int got = recv(data, temp, sizeof(temp), 0);

    fwrite(temp, 1, BUFFSIZE, f);
    total += got;

    if (total == 1568){
    break;
    }
}
fclose(f);
```

BUFFSIZE = 1568

I know that my file is 1568 bytes size, so I try to download it just for a test. Everything is file when I try to download .xml or .html files, but nothing good happens when I try to download png or avi files. Simply original file size is 1568 but got.png file size is 1573. I can't figure out what might cause that.

EDIT:

I have modified my code, so now it looks like (it can accept any file size):

```
FILE *f = fopen("got.png", "w");
    while (1){
        char* temp = (char*)malloc(BUFFSIZE);
        int got = recv(data, temp, BUFFSIZE, 0);

        fwrite(temp, 1, got, f);

        if (got == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
```

Still received file is 2 bytes too long.

Comment: Sounds like a text/binary I/O issue.  Are you running this on Windows by any chance?

Comment: In that case, try opening the file for binary (rather than text) I/O.  And make sure that the reader does the same.

Comment: Amazing! I know that was simple, but you saved my day for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the file in text mode, so bare CR/LF characters are going to get translated to CRLF pairs when written to the file.  You need to open the file in binary mode instead:

```
FILE *f = fopen("got.png", "wb");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always writing a whole buffer even if you have received only a partial one. This is the same problem with ~50% of all TCP questions.

The memset is not necessary. And I hope that temp is an array so that `sizeof(temp)` does not evaluate to the native pointer size. Better use `BUFFSIZE` there as well.

---

Seeing your edit, after fixing the first problem there is another one: Open the file in binary mode.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the problem in this specific case, because the message that the OP gets is *larger* than expected.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. He's writing bigger buffers then expected. We actually now know the MTU of his network :)